# Can anybody help understand what is meant in this pseudocode?

Tags: java, recursion, stack, queue

I have an assignment to do with the Koch Snowflake and stack/queue. The problem is that many of us here cannot figure out what is meant by the pseudocode "hint" given in the assignment. Can anybody help maybe?

http://web.cs.mun.ca/~rod/W12/cs2710/assign/a5/assign5.html

```
Add the initial segments, L.add(seg1) ... L.add(segN)
while not L.isEmpty()
    seg = L.remove()
    if seg is smaller than the minimum segment size then
         draw seg, no new segments are created
    else
        create four new segments according to
        the rules for Koch snowflakes
        add these new segments to L
```

The most confusing part is "if seg is smaller than the minimum segment size"... Not sure what I need to compare to write this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A segment is a Line segment: from your docu:

> "Segment is a class that represents a line segment"

So it will be  a line drawn on the screen.
You should first look how the Koch Snowflake looks alike: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake

Now it is easier to understand: "

> if seg is smaller than the minimum segment size then

This is a so called "break condition" which means the line is small enough that it should be drawn on the screen. (Otherwise it would be sub divided, see the Wiki link above).

Answer (score 2):

The minimum segment size is apparently a configurable parameter of the algorithm that specifies the level of fine detail at which the snowflake is drawn.